# Migrate a Dash app with multiple outputs to Django app

Tags: python, django, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I have a dash app that in my app.py I have functions with many outputs. Is feasible somehow to migrate to Django?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by 'migrate'. Is this you are looking for ? https://thinkinfi.com/integrate-plotly-dash-in-django/

Comment: This is the typical example that exists around but following this doesn't seem to support functions with many outputs. Thank you anyway :)